# Duplicate nodes in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I want to apply a XSL style sheet that delete duplicate nodes in my xml. 
I test some solution but i can't do it :( my program is in Visual C# Studio.

I have the following XML:

```
<store>

 <laptop>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <price>X2</price>
 </laptop>

 <laptop>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <price>X1</price>
 </laptop>

 <laptop>
  <ID>8</ID>
  <price>X2</price>
 </laptop>

 <laptop>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <price>X3</price>
 </laptop>

</store>
```

The desired output is:

```
    <store>

     <laptop>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <price>X2</price>
     </laptop>

     <laptop>
      <ID>8</ID>
      <price>X2</price>
     </laptop>

     <laptop>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <price>X3</price>
     </laptop>

    </store>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below does what you are asking for and works the following way:

1. The first template starts at root and selects all ID tags that does
   not have a ID tag below with the same value (thats why ID 2 comes at
   the end of the output)
2. Loop through the list of ID nodes and output the parent()
   and all of it's children

Comments are welcome, this is my first try at XSL in the last two years.
I tried a xsl:copy but it failed to include the children's tag names, but the values showed up, couldn't figure out why!?

Taken somewhat out of it's contents:

```
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
```

Working code:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <store>
     <xsl:variable name="non-duplicates"
     select="//ID[not(.=following::ID)]" />   

     <xsl:for-each select="$non-duplicates">
       <xsl:copy-of select="parent::*"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </store>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```